# Angular Page Set Title Server Side

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, page-title

Hi so currently in my angular project I am changing the title via the app routes
`{ path: 'prgw/digital', component: SelectedComponent, title: 'You\'ve been selected' }`
Now this is fine client side where once the page loads then the title changes on the tab but lets say you copy the link and send it through sms the preview still shows the default title.

I know there is also the title property where you can set on init but this also shows the same problem where the title only changes when the page loads on client side. Im looking for a solution where if you were to send a sms of the link it will show the same page title of when you would load the page client side.

I've tried changing the title through the app routes also trying to change the title via the Title property this.setTitle("some title") but still the sms preview that displays the title of the page shows the default title the page is set to. Its almost like the title won't change unless you load the page but this solution won't work as I am trying to change the title server side where it shows up on a sms preview.

Comment: Ah no, I'm still using the `Title` service

Comment: Nothing you do in JS will help, that SMS link preview is not going to run your JS anyway. It only looks for the HTML <title> tag, which you can find in index.html. You'd have to use server-side rendering to serve a custom html with the title you want. See https://angular.io/guide/universal